# What does ClamAV do with Google's Safe Browsing?

Tags: google, clamav

I have enabled this functionality in ClamAV:

[image]

But what does this mean? Will it now scan files for these suspicious malware/phishing related URLs? Or...?

Comment: See https://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-faq/blob/master/faq/faq-safebrowsing.md

Comment: To the next who wants to cast a close-vote or a downvote or both: Please leave a note explaining why.

Comment: I understand how you feel Paranoid Panda, , but it is highly unlikely whoever casted the downvote will ever read your comment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-faq/blob/master/faq/faq-safebrowsing.md

> Safebrowsing ClamAV 0.95 introduced support for Google Safe Browsing
>   database. The database is packed inside a CVD file and distributed
>   through our mirror network. This feature is disabled by default on all
>   installations and should be enabled with extreme care.
>
> All signatures provided by Google Safe Browsing Database will be
>   prefixed with the Safebrowsing tag. If ClamAV reports
>   Safebrowsing. FOUND, it means that the advisory was
>   provided by Google and not by ClamAV Virus database.
>
> Please note that such reports DO NOT necessarily mean that the data
>   scanned contains some malware. You should treat such data as a
>   potential risk, that is a suspicious source of malware.
>
> If you want to know more about the potentially dangerous data matched
>   by the signature, you should visit http://www.antiphishing.org (for
>   phishing warnings) or http://www.stopbadware.org (for malware
>   warnings).
>
> In order to enable this feature, you must add SafeBrowsing Yes to
>   freshclam.conf . There is no option in clamd.conf. If the engine finds
>   Google Safe Browsing files in the database directory, ClamAV will
>   enable safe browsing. To turn it off you need to update freshclam.conf
>   and remove the safebrowsing files from the database directory before
>   restarting clamd.